# Can't fetch a field with GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a simple query that will find a person with highest average marks and display some basic information about them. It's retrieving the proper record, but I can't make MySQL display `students.classId` field. The error I'm getting in LibreOffice Base is

> Not in aggregate function or group by clause.

Query with error:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`students`.`surname`, CONCAT(' ', `students`.`name`)) AS `Student`, 
    AVG(CAST(`marks`.`mark` AS DECIMAL (10, 2))) AS `Average`,
    `students`.`classId` 
FROM `students`, `marks`, `subjects` 
WHERE `marks`.`subjectId` = `subjects`.`subjectId` 
    AND `students`.`studentId` = `marks`.`markId`
GROUP BY `students`.`surname`, `students`.`name`
ORDER BY `Average` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Query without error:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`students`.`surname`, CONCAT(' ', `students`.`name`)) AS `Student`, 
    AVG(CAST(`marks`.`mark` AS DECIMAL (10, 2))) AS `Average`
FROM `students`, `marks`, `subjects` 
WHERE `marks`.`subjectId` = `subjects`.`subjectId` 
    AND `students`.`studentId` = `marks`.`markId`
GROUP BY `students`.`surname`, `students`.`name`
ORDER BY `Average` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

I'm not really experienced with SQL, but I think that posting table definitions isn't necessary in this case. If I am wrong, please leave a note in the comments, I'll update the question as soon as possible.

Please note that it is **not** a homework.

Comment: you need to have the columns in the select list before using group by

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I've already tried removing the `CONCAT()` and listing the columns separately, but the error was the same.

Comment: Don't use implcit join syntax - and, as as rule-of-thumb,  you should GROUP BY the same thing that you select [e.g. (CONCAT(s.surname, CONCAT(' ', s.name))]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic item is this:

```
`students`.`classId`
```

Since the `GROUP BY` query produces a single row for one or more rows of the joined tables, that single row may correspond to more than one `students`.`classId` value.

That is what SQL is asking you to fix: it wants to know which of potentially many items of `students`.`classId` you want it to return. The two choices are adding an aggregate function, say

```
MIN(`students`.`classId`) AS StudentClassId
```

or using `students`.`classId` in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY `students`.`surname`, `students`.`name`, `students`.`classId`
```

Note that if you go with the later choice, the aggregation would be per student / class pair, not per student.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the reason it isn't working is because of multiple `classId`'s associated with the student. However, when I run a query for the given student (name + surname), there is only one row with one `classId`. The `MIN()` approach is working, but why can't MySQL fetch the field if there is only one student record?

Comment: @Mateusz "why can't MySQL fetch the field if there is only one student record?" Because then the correctness of the query could change based on the data. Imagine that SQL did what you suggest, and returned a single value when there's only one value to return. What would happen if someone inserted a new row that would give a different `classId`? SQL would have to fail your query that was working "just a minute ago". SQL tries to minimize such unpleasant surprises when it can, so it asks you to fix the query rather than taking a guess that everything will go fine.